# PHP table linkable column

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a query to list al users and i want to be able to click user name ando go to the user info page so my question is how i can pass the user name to the other php.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . ++$i . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='page2.php'><font color='white'>" . $row['1'] . "</font></a></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['2'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['3'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['4'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

The table is fine i just need a way to pass the select user name to the page2.php.

thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . ++$i . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='page2.php?nome='".$row['nome']."><font color='white'>" . $row['nome'] . "</font></a></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['sexo'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['idade'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['diabetes'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

page2.php:

```
    include_once 'ligacao.php';
$name = $_GET['nome'];
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
<tr>
<th><font color='white'>Registo</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Name</font></th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . ++$i . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $name . "</font></td>";

  echo "</tr>";
```

EDIT 2:

How can i align 2 table side by side in the middle of page?

```
    echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><font color='white'>Glicemia</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Hidratos</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Peso</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Descri&ccedil&atildeo</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Timestamp</font></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['glicemia'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['hidratos'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['peso'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['descricao'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['time'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><font color='white'>Medicamento</font></th>
<th><font color='white'>Timestamp</font></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultq)) {
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['medicamento'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font color='white'>" . $row['time'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: And while we're on the subject of depreciated crap, please dont use font tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass it as url parameter and use `$_GET` in `page2.php`, like:

```
...
"<td><a href='page2.php?username='".$row[1].">...</a>
...
```

and in `page2.php`

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

**Update::**
your code seems to have problem with quotes, try changing to:

```
....
echo "<td><a href='page2.php?nome=" . $row['nome'] . "'><font color='white'>" . $row['nome'] . "</font></a></td>";
...
```

Comment: the username is in $row['1']  so if i click that this is gonna show that user name or the last username in the table?

Comment: @user3697305 since your are looping the database records, if $row[1] contains username then it will be added to every td in loop

Comment: i tried i do a echo but i got nothing...shouldn't page2.php?username= show the username selected on the url?

Comment: can u help with 1 more thing how can align 2 table side by side in the middle of page see new edit.